# MongoDb $addToSet where set is deeply nested

Tags: mongodb, graphql

all,

I'm trying to update a MongoDb document using graphQL. I'm trying to add an object to a somewhat deeply nested array in the document, and I'm struggling to work out how to do it.

Here is my typeDef of the thing I want to update:

```
type User {
    _id: ID
    username: String
    email: String
    password: String
    years: [Year]
    bookList: [Booklist]
  }

  type Year {
    _id: ID
    bookcaseYear: String
    bookcase: Bookcase
  }

  type Bookcase {
    _id: ID
    shelves: [Shelf]
    unshelved: [Book]
  }

  type Shelf {
    _id: ID
    left: [Book]
    right: [Book]
  }

  type Book {
    _id: ID
    (various properties here)
  }

  type Booklist {
    _id: ID
    (various properties here)
  }
```

Any guidance would be very appreciated!
So you see it's a user document; the user records the books they've read, and each book gets added in two locations: a `bookList` element that's just a list of all the books, and a `years[bookcase]` element that's an arrangement of those books on their bookcase.

The first part has been easy: find the user and update, putting the book object onto the bookList with a simple `$addToSet`. It's the other part I'm struggling with: adding to the `unshelved` array of that user in the appropriate year's bookcase. At the moment, at least, I just want to add the book to the last bookcase (user.years[user.years.length - 1]) but I'm really struggling to figure out how. Here's my most recent attempt in my resolver:

```
const updateBookcase = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: context.user._id,
            "years.bookcaseYear": "2023",
          },
          { $addToSet: { "years.&.unshelved": args } },
          { new: true }
        );
```

Comment: `years.$.unshelved` instead? Note that this will only update the first matching element. If you want to update multiple matching elements in `years` array, you should look for [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) filtered positional operator.

Comment: That worked after some work at it: your solution helped, Yong Shun! In the process, I determined that what I really needed was two documents, that that was more representative of what I was going for...but your advice did work as well, thanks!